# The six module is causing problems with test coverage using nosetests

Tags: python, python-nose

I'm using `nosetests` and the `coverage` extension to measure the coverage of my unit tests.

I've recently moved to including the `six` module with my package to make it easier for users.

The problem is that having `six` locally seems to mess up the coverage report.

I run my tests like this:

```
nosetests --cover-erase --with-coverage --cover-html --cover-package seaborn
```

The report ends up including references to files that aren't in my directory tree:

```
Name                    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------
ConfigParser              391    391     0%   90-753
HTMLParser                306    306     0%   11-472
Queue                     125    125     0%   3-244
copy_reg                  105    105     0%   7-188
htmlentitydefs              9      9     0%   4-273
httplib                   704    704     0%   69-1342
repr                      103    103     0%   3-132
seaborn                     9      0   100%
<...>
```

The reason I think `six` is causing the problem is that when I search for those names, they only appear in `six.py`:

```
$ git grep ConfigParser
seaborn/external/six.py:    MovedModule("configparser", "ConfigParser"),

$ git grep copy_reg
seaborn/external/six.py:    MovedModule("copyreg", "copy_reg"),
```

At no point in my code do I import `*` from six, all of my imports are specific, like `from .external.six.moves import range`

How can I exclude these objects/files from the coverage report?

I've tried adding `omit = seaborn/external` to my `.coveragerc` (under `[run]`), and that excludes the files in `seaborn/external` from the report, but not the names that `six` seems to be defining.

Comment: Whatever magic six uses to add aliases for the moved modules, it appears to be tricking coverage into thinking these modules are imported and are not part of the standard library (which is excluded by default).

Comment: Have you tried running nose with `--cover-inclusive`?

Comment: `--cover-inclusive` seems not to solve the problem (but does trigger some test errors, weirdly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into your .coveragerc instead.

```
[run]
include = seaborn/*
```

Documentation for configuration - http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html#config

Comment: This does seem to work. Do you have a pointer to something I could read that would explain why?